# In Corda, Could not find method networkMap exception

Tags: corda

I am following instructions on https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V1.0/deploying-a-node.html to add a network map to the `deployNodes` task in 
 my `build.gradle` file. But when I run `gradlew deployNodes`, it gives the following error. I have tried with `Cordform` plugin versions 3.1.0 and 3.2.1 . Am I missing anything or any other setup that needs to be done?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/home/ubuntu/corda/build.gradle' line: 103
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'corda'.
> Could not find method networkMap() for arguments on task ':deployNodes' of type net.corda.plugins.Cordform.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

Answer (score 0):

Corda 3 removed the concept of a special network map node that serves the role of distributing the network map to the other nodes. Instead, the network map is now a collection of signed `NodeInfo` files distributed via HTTP. You can read more about this change [here](https://docs.corda.net/changelog.html#version-3-0).

As a result, the `networkMap` option no longer exists in `Cordform`.